# PHP not loading MySQL dlls on Windows Server 2008

Tags: mysql, php, iis-7

I have a windows server 2008 running IIS7 and PHP 5.2.13 and also an installation of MySQL. However, I have included php_mysql.dll & php_mysqli.dll - I have also moved libmysql.dll from the SQL folder to my php folder and also to the system32 folder. Furthermore I have checked all my directories, created an environment path etc, but it still doesn't show up in my php.info (also activated in the CORRECT php.ini folder). I reset every time I make a change as well.

Any help would be great!

Comment: The title of your question is very meta - please edit it to actually describe what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I've had problems with non-php/non-mysql libraries not being in the correct locations before.

[Dynamic Library Loads Fail](https://serverfault.com/questions/81244/php-5-2-11-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-complaints)

Just something else to check.  Obviously the standard stop/start services and all that jazz would apply too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, not this either - the only other extension is php_curl.dll and that works fine.

Comment: Have you cranked the error reporting up in the php.ini?  Usually php itself will give you some clues as to being able to load a library or not.

Comment: It's definitely not loading the library - function could not be found, also non-existant in the phpinfo()

Comment: can you paste in (or use pastebin or some such) your php.ini file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Jxm1z3Xv - cheers

Comment: As long as this is a non-production machine, lets change the following: display_errors = On and display_startup_errors = On, then restart IIS and reload your phpinfo() page and hopefully we'll see an actual error about what's going on.  You might also look at your event log for errors.

Comment: Cheers oldtroll. On the phpinfo there is no error from what I can see. I think I may just reinstall php and compile it at build, because this is fairly old anyways and needs a clean up? Thanks for your help as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload PHP for configuration changes to take effect. Restart IIS and check again if you're sure everything else is done correctly.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I already run iisreset.exe every time